Bond Basis (non CTD)
I had a query regarding the trading of non CTD (but deliverable) basis. Obviously someone can buy non CTD basis (buy cash / sell bond future), with the hopes this widens, clearly I would not want to ever deliver this bond into the future.
Therefore, is the point of the trade that there is a hope that the net basis of this particular bond widens? to me then, there are two angles to the trade: The trade of the non-cheap bond versus the CTD (i.e. the bond RV angle) and then the CTD basis. Just really want confirmation if this line of thinking is correct, as it feels like most of the juice in these trades is not actually in CTD basis but cheap surrounding issues.

To the extent the future is (for the short term at least) a substitute for the CTD, the trade you have in mind is similar to (Long non-CTD, short CTD).

Sure, so is this just Rv?

so if i buy a near to CTD bond and sell a future versus it, do I have a put or a call? or does it depend
